# Cygnus test problems

Tags: fiware-cygnus

I have installed Cygnus and when I do the test I have 4 errors, 2 in com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.utils.TestUtils.txt file and other 2 in com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.utils.TestConstants.txt.

The errors are as follows:

```
#more com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.utils.TestConstants.txt
------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Test set: com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.utils.TestConstants
------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.009 sec <<< FAILURE! initializationError(com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.utils.TestConstants)  Time elapsed: 0.003 sec  <<< ERROR! java.lang.Exception: Test class should have exactly one public constructor
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.validateOnlyOneConstructor(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:134)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.validateConstructor(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:123)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.collectInitializationErrors(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.validate(ParentRunner.java:355)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:76)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
        at org.junit.internal.builders.JUnit4Builder.runnerForClass(JUnit4Builder.java:10)
        at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
        at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
        at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
        at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:26)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.<init>(JUnit4TestSet.java:45)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4DirectoryTestSuite.createTestSet(JUnit4DirectoryTestSuite.java:56)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.locateTestSets(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:96)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.Surefire.createSuiteFromDefinition(Surefire.java:209)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.Surefire.run(Surefire.java:156)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireBooter.java:345)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.main(SurefireBooter.java:1009)

initializationError(com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.utils.TestConstants)  Time elapsed: 0 sec  <<< ERROR! java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.validateInstanceMethods(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:169)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.collectInitializationErrors(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:104)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.validate(ParentRunner.java:355)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:76)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
        at org.junit.internal.builders.JUnit4Builder.runnerForClass(JUnit4Builder.java:10)
        at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
        at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
        at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
        at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:26)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.<init>(JUnit4TestSet.java:45)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4DirectoryTestSuite.createTestSet(JUnit4DirectoryTestSuite.java:56)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.locateTestSets(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:96)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.Surefire.createSuiteFromDefinition(Surefire.java:209)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.Surefire.run(Surefire.java:156)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireBooter.java:345)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.main(SurefireBooter.java:1009)


# more com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.utils.TestUtils.txt
------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Test set: com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.utils.TestUtils
------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.003 sec <<< FAILURE! initializationError(com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.utils.TestUtils)  Time elapsed: 0 sec  <<< ERROR! java.lang.Exception: Test class should have exactly one public constructor
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.validateOnlyOneConstructor(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:134)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.validateConstructor(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:123)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.collectInitializationErrors(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.validate(ParentRunner.java:355)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:76)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
        at org.junit.internal.builders.JUnit4Builder.runnerForClass(JUnit4Builder.java:10)
        at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
        at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
        at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
        at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:26)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.<init>(JUnit4TestSet.java:45)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4DirectoryTestSuite.createTestSet(JUnit4DirectoryTestSuite.java:56)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.locateTestSets(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:96)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.Surefire.createSuiteFromDefinition(Surefire.java:209)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.Surefire.run(Surefire.java:156)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireBooter.java:345)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.main(SurefireBooter.java:1009)

initializationError(com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.utils.TestUtils)  Time elapsed: 0 sec  <<< ERROR! java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.validateInstanceMethods(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:169)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.collectInitializationErrors(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:104)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.validate(ParentRunner.java:355)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:76)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
        at org.junit.internal.builders.JUnit4Builder.runnerForClass(JUnit4Builder.java:10)
        at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
        at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
        at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
        at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:26)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.<init>(JUnit4TestSet.java:45)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4DirectoryTestSuite.createTestSet(JUnit4DirectoryTestSuite.java:56)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.locateTestSets(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:96)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.Surefire.createSuiteFromDefinition(Surefire.java:209)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.Surefire.run(Surefire.java:156)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireBooter.java:345)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.main(SurefireBooter.java:1009)
```

The agent.conf file is:

```
cygnusagent.sources = http-source
cygnusagent.sinks = ckan-sink mongo-sink
cygnusagent.channels = ckan-channel mongo-channel

#=============================================
# source configuration
# channel name where to write the notification events

cygnusagent.sources.http-source.channels = ckan-channel mongo-channel
# source class, must not be changed
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.type = org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource
# listening port the Flume source will use for receiving incoming notifications
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.port = 5050
# Flume handler that will parse the notifications, must not be changed
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.handlers.OrionRestHandler

# URL target
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.notification_target = /notify
# Default service (service semantic depends on the persistence sink)
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.default_service = def_serv
# Default service path (service path semantic depends on the persistence sink)
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.default_service_path = def_servpath
# Number of channel re-injection retries before a Flume event is definitely discarded (-1 means infinite retries)
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.events_ttl = 10
# Source interceptors, do not change
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors = ts gi
# TimestampInterceptor, do not change
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors.ts.type = timestamp
# GroupinInterceptor, do not change
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors.gi.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.interceptors.GroupingInterceptor$Builder

# Grouping rules for the GroupingInterceptor, put the right absolute path to the file if necessary
# See the doc/design/interceptors document for more details
###cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors.gi.grouping_rules_conf_file = /usr/cygnus/conf/grouping_rules_1.conf
# ============================================
# OrionCKANSink configuration
# channel name from where to read notification events
cygnusagent.sinks.ckan-sink.channel = ckan-channel
# sink class, must not be changed
cygnusagent.sinks.ckan-sink.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.OrionCKANSink
#Â true if the grouping feature is enabled for this sink, false otherwise
cygnusagent.sinks.ckan-sink.enable_grouping = false
# the CKAN API key to use
cygnusagent.sinks.ckan-sink.api_key = ckanapikey
# the FQDN/IP address for the CKAN API endpoint
cygnusagent.sinks.ckan-sink.ckan_host = CKANIP
# the port for the CKAN API endpoint
cygnusagent.sinks.ckan-sink.ckan_port = CKANPORT
# Orion URL used to compose the resource URL with the convenience operation URL to query it
cygnusagent.sinks.ckan-sink.orion_url = http://localhost:1026
# how the attributes are stored, either per row either per column (row, column)
cygnusagent.sinks.ckan-sink.attr_persistence = row
# enable SSL for secure Http transportation; 'true' or 'false'
cygnusagent.sinks.ckan-sink.ssl = false
# number of notifications to be included within a processing batch
cygnusagent.sinks.ckan-sink.batch_size = 100
# timeout for batch accumulation
cygunsagent.sinks.ckan-sink.batch_timeout = 30

# ============================================
# OrionMongoSink configuration
# sink class, must not be changed
cygnusagent.sinks.mongo-sink.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.OrionMongoSink
# channel name from where to read notification events
cygnusagent.sinks.mongo-sink.channel = mongo-channel
#Â true if the grouping feature is enabled for this sink, false otherwise
cygnusagent.sinks.mongo-sink.enable_grouping = false
# FQDN/IP:port where the MongoDB server runs (standalone case) or comma-separated list of FQDN/IP:port pairs where the MongoDB replica set members run
cygnusagent.sinks.mongo-sink.mongo_hosts = ORIONIP:ORIONPORT
# a valid user in the MongoDB server (or empty if authentication is not enabled in MongoDB)
cygnusagent.sinks.mongo-sink.mongo_username =
# password for the user above (or empty if authentication is not enabled in MongoDB)
cygnusagent.sinks.mongo-sink.mongo_password =
# prefix for the MongoDB databases
###cygnusagent.sinks.mongo-sink.db_prefix = sth_
# prefix pro the MongoDB collections
###cygnusagent.sinks.mongo-sink.collection_prefix = sth_
# true is collection names are based on a hash, false for human redable collections
cygnusagent.sinks.mongo-sink.should_hash = false

# specify if the sink will use a single collection for each service path, for each entity or for each attribute  
###cygnusagent.sinks.mongo-sink.data_model = collection-per-entity  
# how the attributes are stored, either per row either per column (row, column) 
###cygnusagent.sinks.mongo-sink.attr_persistence = column  
#=============================================  
# ckan-channel configuration  
# channel type (must not be changed)  
cygnusagent.channels.ckan-channel.type = memory  
# capacity of the channel  
cygnusagent.channels.ckan-channel.capacity = 1000  
# amount of bytes that can be sent per transaction  
cygnusagent.channels.ckan-channel.transactionCapacity = 100  
#=============================================  
# mongo-channel configuration  
# channel type (must not be changed)  
cygnusagent.channels.mongo-channel.type = memory  
# capacity of the channel  
cygnusagent.channels.mongo-channel.capacity = 1000  
# amount of bytes that can be sent per transaction  
cygnusagent.channels.mongo-channel.transactionCapacity = 100
```

Could someone help me?

Thanks

Comment: Which is the exact command you are running? Which version of Cygnus are you using?

Comment: The cygnus version is cygnus-0.11.0-1.g2a9c87f.x86_64 and I checked with the test mentioned in the manual. http://fiware-cygnus.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation_and_administration_guide/testing/index.html

Comment: I've tested it and it works for me, as can be seen in this pastebin: http://pastebin.com/EXJqci1c

Comment: Do you have any different configuration?

Comment: The tests don't take any configuration. If you have a look on my commands sequence, you'll see I've simply cloned the repo, changed the directory, checked the current branch is master and finally run the tests. Try doing the same steps and let me know the result.

Comment: I've tried again an this is the result: [http://pastebin.com/nP9wBYTm](http://pastebin.com/nP9wBYTm)

Comment: Please see in the next url the steeps that I did and the results with errors: [http://pastebin.com/UxjhtMzf]

Comment: Sorry, the before link was deleted. See the errors in the next link: http://pastebin.com/tU5hxTXk

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary update the Maven to the last version.
I have installed the Maven v.3.3.9 and now the error does not appear.